# Icon and Splash screen not showing correctly from resources in Andrioid

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been working with Ionic project. I am not getting my app's icon and splash screen from resources folder. whereas it is showing by default cordova image as icon and splash screen in android.
also tries `ionic resources` command. why I am not getting my images from resources ?

**ionic info**

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.3.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.16
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.3
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v4.4.7

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget android-versionCode="41" id="com.vs.hybrid.emc" version="3.000.001" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>EMC</name>
  <description>An instant cab booking application</description>
  <author email="support@abc.com" href="http://www.example.com/">Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="20000"/>
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="false"/>
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: If you have changed something in your config, you have to build your platforms again.

Comment: It's a bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12077. it has been fixed and will be released as soon as possible

Comment: @Joerg I build every time when make changes

Comment: @jcesarmobile utill it releases, what is solution ?

Comment: `cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-android`

Comment: What @daserge said, or the previous version with cordova platform add cordova platform add android@5.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the backslash to forward slash. 
Example:-

```
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
```

Reference link:-
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html

Comment: I did this, but no luck

Comment: how ever this helped me along-with degrading cordova version to 5.4.1